# Unable to log in to Ubuntu server 10.04 after trying to join Windows domain

Tags: ubuntu, pam, domain

I was trying to join our Ubuntu 10.04 server to the Windows domain and I ended up editing the `pam.d` configuration files. My aim was to have domain users log into the Ubuntu server with their domain accounts in order to access some applications instead of creating new Unix users each time.

My system admin says the join was successful to the domain. Now I have no way of logging into the sever.

Is there a way I can undo everything and get the server back to the original login using the local account?

I will also appreciate if someone pointed me to some configuration that actually worked - I am still willing to try and make it work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to boot your Ubuntu server in rescue mode then you can revert back to default settings by manually editing files. Refer this page for [how to boot into rescue mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode) 
after booting in to rescue mode, you need to check "/etc/nsswitch.conf", "/etc/pam.d/common-account" this files are important for log in then change those file as default with help of other ubuntu server in your end.

also you can use live cd and do the required changes

the default nsswitch.conf file available in "/usr/share/base-files/nsswitch.conf"

Comment: Thanks was able to fix this using a live cd. I copied all the files in the pam.d folder into my /etc/pam.d/ folder. Now I am able to log in.

Comment: and thanks for pointing out the location of the default files